# compiler error using enum in Salesforce Apex class

Tags: salesforce, apex-code

I was trying to use enum in my Salesforce Apex Class, but got complier errors.

I copied the enum example from their documentation http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/apexcode/Content/langCon_apex_enums.htm

```
global class DataTablesExtension{

     public enum Season {WINTER, SPRING, SUMMER, FALL}
     ....
}
```

but got an "unexpected token: 'WINTER'" error when saving

Also tried to create a separate enum class as their documentation suggested,

```
public enum MyEnumClass { X, Y }
```

and got an "unexpected token: 'public enum'" error when saving

Have anyone tried this? and what did I miss?

Comment: It's strange. I've created class with inner enum without any troubles in my developer edition via web UI. I just removed the dots from your example with seasons.

Comment: I agree very strange behavior. Try to change public to global maybe in 1st example.

Comment: no, use public class didn't work either.

Comment: @user1893399, as the problem is really very strange could you please provide a screenshot with error?

Comment: it working now -- I didn't change anything within that class since I tested it this morning.

Comment: I'm having almost the same problem when deploying change set from sandbox to production. I have another error but it disappears in 11.5 hours w/o editing any class or deploying another Change Set. mystic...

Answer (score 0):

How are you referencing WINTER? If you declare a new Season object its value has to be Season.WINTER, not WINTER.